# Implementation of ISATAP Protocol

Tags: c++, network-programming, packet, packet-capture, winpcap

Can anybody help me figure out how to implement ISATAP packet?

I'm creating packets in C++ (Winpcap). I can't imagine how it should be.

Specification: http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/isatap.htm

Is that an example of ISATAP packet?

> 0000 5EFE C0A8 0110
>
> (IP Address - 192.168.1.16)
>
> 4548 9559 (Some data)

Comment: Looks right to me based on that link. Are you simply expecting a "yes" or "no" answer? It looks like you did imagine how it should be, since you put what you think it might be in your question...

Answer (score 0):

According to specification the packet for 192.168.1.16 which is not globally uniqe (U bit set to 0) should look like in hexadecimal

```
00 00 5E FE
C0 A8 01 10
Some data
```

So it's correct